# Laravel Middleware not working on particular method

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to use middleware in `Usercontroller` on only `getDashboard()` and `getUserlist()` method, but it didn't work for me.
also I add in controller constructor.

**My Controller:**

```
class Usercontroller extends Controller {

public function __construct() {
$this->middleware('auth',['only' => ['getDashboard']]);
//$this->middleware('auth');
}

##This method render home view.

public function index() {
    //  dd('yahoo');
    return view('welcome');
}
 ##To add new user.

public function getAdduser() {
    return view('register');
}

#To render dashboard view.

public function getDashboard() {
    return view('dashboard');
}
```

When I directly type in url `http://localhost/rabble/index.php/user/dashboard`.it still display display without authenticate user is login or not.

Comment: Did you checked if `auth` middleware works when enabled without only option?

Comment: yes it works without only